# How to trigger an evenement on export Odoo

Tags: python-2.7, export, odoo

I have an ir.config_parameter I'd like to update when a specific field of my res_partner table is exported, for exemple if "age" is exported, I want the higgest ID in res_partner to be stored in my config_parameter named "last_age". How can I trigger a set_param(cr, uid, 'my_module.last_age', 'higgest_id') when age is exported?

Do I have to overwrite the export if it's even possible?

Thanks

EDIT:

I did this in my res.partner:

```
def export_data(self, cr, uid, ids, fields_to_export, context=None):
    super(res_partner, self).export_data(cr, uid, ids, fields_to_export, context=context)
```

But in the first line, an error occur:
TypeError: export_data() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'

If I delete `context=None`, an other error occur: 
TypeError: export_data() takes exactly 5 arguments (7 given)
Same error if I remove `self`

Really few occurence of "export_data()" appear in google, I searched a lot but found nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "exported"? An csv export?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Odoo model will inherit Model/TransienModel (older versions osv.osv) which comes with already defined methods, like read, search, create, ...

Odoo's export (csv. excel) is using the method export_data(). Just override it and set your parameter within it.

Comment: Do you have any documentation about how to override export_data()? I found almost nothing, and I don't know if I have to create a new class or redefine in res.partner. I tried a new class as I found in an answer on a forum, it compile but the first data_export (not overrriden) is called and not the new one. I also tried inside the res.partner but it always give me an error.

Comment: You have to extend `res.partner` for that and redefine export_data() on it. Make a super() call to report the data in the end. An example how to extend an odoo model: [sale_stock](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/sale_stock/sale_stock.py#L156)