# Storing an int in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'd like to know if their is a way to store an integer somewhere in odoo, without having to create an new objet. I'd like to keep a number in order to show only partner with an id superior to that number. But I don't want to add a field in every single record of res.partner. How can I have a number I can acces into my xml without it being a field of res.partner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the model `ir.config_parameter` for such cases. Get used to the medhod set_param() and get_param().

The parameter holds his value as string, so for my example it will be parsed into integer. The xml id will be `my_module.test_parameter`.

But using this within the view is a bit tricky. A way would be a filter with a context "signal" within the search view of the model:

```py
<filter name="my_filter" string="My Filter" context="{'search_by_parameter':1}" />
```

With that you could override the search() of your model to use the parameter when the filter was activated:

```py
def search(self, cr, uid, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, context=None, count=False):
    context = dict(context or {})
    if 'search_by_parameter' in context:
        try:
            value = int(self.pool.get('ir.config_parameter').get_param(cr, uid, 'my_module.test_parameter'))
        except:
            value = 0
        args.append(('id', '>', value))
    return super(my_model, self).search(cr, uid, args, offset, limit, order, context, count)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to find some documentation on this.

Comment: Sorry to add one question but:
Where do you set the parameter? I tried in a transient model as I saw on other discussions, but it doesn't seems to be how it should be here. (I'd like to save the higgest id when a specific field of res_partner is exported). Do you know how I should do it? Do I have to create a new class?

Comment: The model/class is already there: `ir.config_parameter`. You can find the default parameters under Settings/Technical/Paramters/System Parameters. Just create a config_parameter by using xml record in your module and use this one for your purpose. Implement a set_param() call into your export execution, to save a new value into the config_parameter.

Comment: Yes I found it, but how do I set a new value to the parameter each time an export happen? (For fields i'd use api.depends, but here it isn't a field and the action isn't a field being changed, but an export). I edited one of my previous question if you want better explaination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917368/how-to-trigger-an-evenement-on-export-odoo . I'm sorry not to be clear.